# Construct a Liapunov function for this system

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, control-theory

Construct a **Liapunov function** for the system (**Determine the stability of $x \equiv 0$**):

I have an example:$$\begin{cases}
 & \mathrm { } \dot{x}= -x^3+xy^2\\ 
 & \mathrm { } \dot{y}= -2x^2y-y^3
\end{cases}  \tag{1}$$

**Here's my solution:**

- Let's try $V(x,y)=ax^2+by^2$.

Then we have: $\dot{V}(x,y)=-2ax^4+2(a-2b)x^2y^2-2by^4$

- When $a-2b<0$, for instance $a=b=1$. We have $V(x,y)=x^2+y^2$ such that: 
  $$V(0,0)=0,V(x,y)>0, \forall (x,y) \ne (0,0)\ \text{and} \ \dot{V}(x,y)<0$$
- Hence, $x=y=0$ is **asymptotically stable**.

============================================================

What about the system:

$$\begin{cases}
 & \mathrm{  } \dot{x}= y-3x^3\\ 
 & \mathrm{  } \dot{y}= -x-7y^3
\end{cases} \tag{2}$$

How can we construct a **Liapunov function** for this system (Determine the stability of $x \equiv 0$ of the system).

I'm sorry I fixed it!

Comment: If one system is $(1)$, the other one should be $(2)$

Comment: Yes, $(2)$ Hihi :) It's a typo! ** Robert Israel**

Answer (score 2):

I doubt that there is a closed-form global Liapunov function.  Note that  besides the centre at $(0,0)$ you have critical points at $(\pm \sqrt{3}/3,\mp 7 \sqrt{3}/9)$, which I think are saddle points.

EDIT: It looks like e.g.
$$ V(x,y) = {x}^{2}+{y}^{2}+ 8.75\,x{y}^{3}+3\,{x}^{2}{y}^{2}+ 5.25\,{x}^{3}y$$
is a Liapunov function for $(x,y)$ near $(0,0)$.

EDIT: How could I find this? By symmetry, I wanted something invariant under
$ x \to -x,\; y \to -y$, so terms of even total degree in $x$,$y$.  So start
with $x^2 + y^2 + \sum_{i=0}^4 a_i x^i y^{4-i}$.  The lowest-order terms of
$\dot{V}$ are of total degree $4$ in $x,y$. I then substituted $x = \cos(s)$, $y = \sin(s)$ into those terms, and chose $a_0, \ldots, a_4$ so that the
result was negative for all $s \in [0,2\pi]$.  The one above is far from the only 
possible choice (and I don't remember exactly why I chose that particular one).

Comment: You mean we consider the system of equation: $$\begin{cases}
 & \mathrm{  } 0= y-3y^3\\ 
 & \mathrm{  } 0= -x-7y^3
\end{cases}; $$ Whence, $$(x,y) \in \{(0,0);(-\dfrac{7}{3\sqrt{3}},\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{3}}), (\dfrac{7}{3 \sqrt{3}},-\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{3}}) \}$$. And what We're going to do? You can tell me more? Plz!

Comment: Wow! OMG It's too long! Hihi :) I'm sorry when I have a question: **how** do you find it? Plz!

Comment: It's great! You're very intelligent! **Robert Israel**. I'll check it, but I think that you're correct! :)

Comment: But my question is **Determine the stability of $x\equiv 0$** of $(2)$. I think that your function $V(x,y)$ is too complex. I suspect that it is *simpler*, maybe. But, now I haven't  found it. :(

Comment: The fact that this is a Liapunov function with a local minimum at $(0,0)$ shows that $(0,0)$ is asymptotically stable.

Comment: If $x=1,y=-1$ then $V(1,-1)=-9<0$? we need $V(x,y)>0$? **Robert Israel**?

Comment: As I said, it's only a local minimum, reflecting the fact that $(0,0)$ is only a local attractor, not a global attractor.

Comment: Thanks **Robert Israel**! I will read carefully your ANS, but as I said I think that you're correct :) !

Comment: I'm sorry! I fixed it $$\begin{cases}
 & \mathrm{  } \dot{x}= y-3x^3\\ 
 & \mathrm{  } \dot{y}= -x-7y^3
\end{cases} \tag{2}$$

Comment: That makes it much less interesting.  You just need a quadratic.

Comment: Yes, **Robert Israel**! Hihi :). Thank you very much! And I found $V(x,y)=x^2+y^2$ as you said.

Comment: @ **Robert Israel**: For the system of equations: $$\begin{cases}
 & \mathrm{  } \dot{x}= y-3x^3\\ 
 & \mathrm{  } \dot{y}= -x-7y^3
\end{cases} \tag{2}$$. Since your hints, I found $V(x,y)=x^2+y^2$. And $x \equiv 0$ is **Uniformly Asymptotically Stable**. Is that correct? Thanks!